How to save django db data in the middle of a playwright test?
I'm having trouble figuring out how to call the "sync" create_user().
Error message:
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: 
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

However, when I use sync_to_async, it cannot be awaited because this is not an async function...
from functools import wraps

from django.test import TestCase
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


def playwright_test(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with sync_playwright() as self.p:
            self.browser = self.p.chromium.launch()
            self.page = self.browser.new_page()
            try:
                result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                self.browser.close()
            return result

    return wrapper


class TC(TestCase):
    @playwright_test
    def test_login(self):
        self.page.goto(self.host)
        self.page.fill('input[type="email"]', 'my@email.com')
        self.page.fill('input[type="password"]', 'TestLogin')
        self.page.click('text="Login"')
        # expect "Incorrect Credentials" message (no user created yet)
        assert "Incorrect Credentials" in self.page.content()

        User = get_user_model()
        User.objects.create_user('my@email.com', password='TestLogin')

        # Login again, this time successfully
        self.page.fill('input[type="email"]', 'my@email.com')
        self.page.fill('input[type="password"]', 'TestLogin')
        self.page.click('text="Login"')
        assert "Login successful. Welcome back!" in self.page.content()

If you have a suggestion, please let me know, my hair starts to fall out. 

Why would you create user inside of test and not in setUp?

Does it work without @playwright_test decorator? Your code looks fine and it is strange it returns this error.

Thanks for looking into my issue @iklinac! I wanted to test the capabilities of playwright with python. I could do as you say in this case, but later I may want to query the db to confirm that the app and the db has the same data in some tests, and then I cannot go into tearDown with an assertion.

Thanks for looking into my code @ViAchKoN, you mean if I put the with block into test_login?
(I agree it is a strange error, the AI's both chatgpt and copilot were puzzled...)

I mean would be good to remove @playwright_test alltogether and check whether you get the same error. I have a suspicion that playwright_test is somehow is working in async context although it states otherwise.

Or you can try to not use playwright_test as a decorator but instead run the code directly without context manager to see how it will behave.

Or you can try sync_to_async when calling User.objects.create_user('my@email.com', password='TestLogin'). Although it is really strange that you might need to do that.

Thanks, I went down the sync_to_async road, there was no luck with that, because the function is sync, so I could not "await" it. I have no idea how to do it without the context manager.
It would be nice to see how it should work, but I went back to Selenium for now, I have plenty of experience there anyway, and was looking into Playwright only for the trace feature.

As @CoffeeBasedLifeform generously wrote in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78651148/1031191 ,
for django the solution is https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-pytest/issues/29#issuecomment-731515676
Copying the link contents here:

For running Django tests with playwright you need to set environment
variable DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE = "true" django docs on this
This can be done by
creating a conftest.py in the tests directory and setting the
environment variable using
# conftest.py import os 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE","true")



You can avoid the error message with this:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-pytest/issues/29#issuecomment-731515676
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/439

Maybe that's enough to let you continue (I'm using that workaround pretty much everywhere).

As for the test itself, you could try something like this:
Run two tests, one where the user was not created, and one where it was created (via fixture create_user).
# conftest.py

# https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/439
# https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-pytest/issues/29#issuecomment-731515676
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE", "true")

# test_login.py
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


@pytest.fixture
def user_email():
    return "my@email.com"


@pytest.fixture
def user_password():
    return "TestLogin"


@pytest.fixture
def create_user(user_email, user_password):
    return get_user_model().objects.create_user(user_email, password=user_password)


@pytest.fixture
def host():
    return "?"


class TestLogin:
    def test_login_fail_no_user(self, page, host, user_email, user_password):
        page.goto(host)
        page.fill('input[type="email"]', user_email)
        page.fill('input[type="password"]', user_password)
        page.click('text="Login"')
        # expect "Incorrect Credentials" message (no user created yet)
        assert "Incorrect Credentials" in page.content()

    def test_login_success(self, create_user, page, host, user_email, user_password):
        page.goto(host)
        page.fill('input[type="email"]', user_email)
        page.fill('input[type="password"]', user_password)
        page.click('text="Login"')
        # Login again, this time successfully
        assert "Login successful. Welcome back!" in page.content()

Or a bit more DRY:
@pytest.fixture
def try_login(page, host, user_email, user_password):
    page.goto(host)
    page.fill('input[type="email"]', user_email)
    page.fill('input[type="password"]', user_password)
    page.click('text="Login"')
    return page


class TestLogin:
    def test_login_fail_no_user(self, page, try_login):
        # expect "Incorrect Credentials" message (no user created yet)
        assert "Incorrect Credentials" in page.content()

    def test_login_success(self, create_user, page, try_login):
        # Login again, this time successfully
        assert "Login successful. Welcome back!" in page.content()


Hey @CoffeeBasedLifeform, thanks for the two links (+1), indeed the environment variable DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE is probably what I need to set.
These fixtures everywhere in pytest feel super tacky tbh. You'll need to keep including more and more "fixtures" magically in your test functions and I don't like magic variable naming, because it does not self-document.

It's not tacky. pytest is designed around having lots of modular fixtures: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/fixtures.html The fixtures also document what a test does.
